# React 404 page not working with CSSTransition

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I need to apply a 404 error page to ReactJs with CSSTransition. This is working fine when I using it with **react-router-dom Switch**. But, I need to implement CSSTransition with React Router. Idea from http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router. Codes are following,

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import InvalidPage from './InvalidPage';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Users from './Users';
import UserNew from './UserNew';

const routes = [
  { path: '/admin/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', Component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/admin/user', name: 'Users', Component: Users },
  { path: '/admin/new-user', name: 'Add New User', Component: UserNew }
  { path: '/admin/404', name: '404 Error', Component: InvalidPage }
]

function SiteRoutes() {
  return(
    routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
      <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
        {
          ({ match }) => (
            <CSSTransition
              in={match != null}
              timeout={300}
              classNames="page"
              unmountOnExit>
              <div className="page">
                <Component />
                {console.log(match != null)}
              </div>
            </CSSTransition>
          )
        }
      </Route>
    ))
  );
}

export default SiteRoutes;
```

When I click on undefined route **(e.g: /admin/edit-user)** then it's showing blank page. But, I need a 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to ensure inlcuding a 404 page in react are:

> exact={false} 
> path="*" 
> The component should look like `<Route path="*" component={NotFoundComponent} />`

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match

> Note: Please let me know in comments if I did not understand the problem statement.

This should redirect any unknown/unregistered route to your 404 component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import InvalidPage from './InvalidPage';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Users from './Users';
import UserNew from './UserNew';

const routes = [
  { path: '/admin/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', Component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/admin/user', name: 'Users', Component: Users },
  { path: '/admin/new-user', name: 'Add New User', Component: UserNew }
  { path: '/admin/404', name: '404 Error', Component: InvalidPage },
  { path: '*', name: '404 Error', Component: InvalidPage }
]

function SiteRoutes() {
  return(
    routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
      <Route key={path} exact={path!=="*"} path={path}>
        {
          ({ match }) => (
            <CSSTransition
              in={match != null}
              timeout={300}
              classNames="page"
              unmountOnExit>
              <div className="page">
                <Component />
                {console.log(match != null)}
              </div>
            </CSSTransition>
          )
        }
      </Route>
    ))
  );
}

export default SiteRoutes;
```

Comment: No, this will redirect all routes, regardless of URL, to the 404 route

Comment: Actually, while this answer didn't get it exactly right, it put me on the right path. The 404 route needs to go first. In a `Switch`,  the first matching route will be displayed, without it that last one will.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing a blank page on `/admin/edit-user` because this route doesn't matches with any of the path you defined.

You need to add a empty path for this. Reason:

> A `<Route>` with no path will always match.

So, add this route `<Route component={InvalidPage} />` at the end, so when a user goes to a undefined route like `/admin/edit-user/` this empty route will match and `InvalidPage` component will be rendered.

Also wrap all your routes in Switch, so that only the first matching route matches. Without Switch multiple routes can match, which I think is not desired.

Comment: It's not working. I have alreay tried before. `{ path: '', name: '404 Error', Component: InvalidPage }` This way appear both component on the same time.

Comment: That's why you need to wrap all your routes with `<Switch/>` @TheWPCracker

Comment: [According to this](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router/), wrapping routes with `Switch` won't work. I can verify with my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

I also was working with that code example.

It seems like overkill (like there must be a better way) but the only way I was able to have a catch all route was to make the last `Route` check the path against supported paths.

EDIT: changed my code example to match OP.
EDIT 2: fixed error; tested code

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import InvalidPage from "./InvalidPage";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Users from "./Users";
import UserNew from "./UserNew";

const routes = [
  { path: "/admin/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", Component: Dashboard },
  { path: "/admin/user", name: "Users", Component: Users },
  { path: "/admin/new-user", name: "Add New User", Component: UserNew }
];

function SiteRoutes() {
  const routeComponents = routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
    <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
      {({ match }) => (
        <CSSTransition
          in={match != null}
          timeout={300}
          classNames="page"
          unmountOnExit
        >
          <div className="page">
            <Component />
            {console.log(match != null)}
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      )}
    </Route>
  ));

  routeComponents.push(
    <Route>
      {routeProps => {
        console.log(routeProps);
        if ( routes.filter(r => r.path === routeProps.location.pathname).length === 0 ) {
          return (
            <CSSTransition
              in={routeProps.match != null}
              timeout={300}
              classNames="fade"
              unmountOnExit
            >
              <InvalidPage />
            </CSSTransition>
          );
        } else {
          return <div></div>;
        }
      }}
    </Route>
  );

  return routeComponents;
}

export default SiteRoutes;
```

Comment: I am not sure about `routePaths` and `routeProps`. Can you please describe them? Or can you please swap your codes with the given format. Thanks

Comment: In the original example, `match` is made available by deconstructing the props passed into the `Route`. Instead of doing that, I pass in the route's props as `routeProps`.

Comment: After swapping your codes, page not working and console saying, **Uncaught ReferenceError: routePaths is not defined**. Please check the link - https://prnt.sc/oy0nl5

Comment: @TheWPCracker: I have fixed the code and tested it in a `create-react-app` instance. This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Now all the static routes working fine. But, dynamic routes not working. e.g: `http://localhost:8000/admin/user/5`.

Comment: Were they working before using the `CSSTransition` component? It looks like they wouldn't work because the `Route`'s all have `exact` paths. This line would make each route have to exactly match:
`<Route key={path} exact path={path}>`

Comment: I have removed **exact** from `<Route key={path} exact path={path}>` but, it's working like before. When I am on a single page (e.g: http://localhost:8000/admin/user/5) both of components (`UserSingle` and `InvalidPage`) appear on the screen. Please note, I also add a new line to the **routes** array `{ path: "/admin/user/:id", name: "View User", Component: UserSingle }`